# how to perform std::find on const char *

Tags: c++

I am trying to improve my plain text reader performance by using nmap to map file to memory.
Currently I have a function that receives const char * and length of that array. And I need to perform search on this char array.

This is what I currenly have

```
void parseVertex(
    const char * line, 
    unsigned int length, 
   std::vector<glm::vec3> & vertices)
{
    if(length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    char space = ' ';


    char * pos = std::find(line, line + length, space);
}
```

`std::find` produces error : **a value of type const char * cannot be used to initialize an entity of type char ***

What is the correct way to use `std::find` ?

Comment: Well, isn't it **a little bit** suspicious? Do you care about const correctness?

Comment: This isn't actually nessesery but I am trying to learn how to protect variables from editing by accident, in this code line shouldn't be altered so there is `const`

Comment: you're on the right track and you should by all means be doing this. It's just that you must keep in mind that `std::find()` return a pointer from within the original string if found (of course), so the original string was composed of `const char`s, the return value should also point to `const char`, since if it didn't, it would be possible to modify the string through the returned pointer, and that's a constraint violation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::find` return-type depends on what you pass to it.

`line` is `const char*`, so `std::find` will return `const char*`, NOT `char*`. So write this:

```
const char * pos = std::find(line, line + length, space);
```

Likewise, if you pass `char*`, you will get `char*`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All of the answers were correct but your's was well explained so I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Make it

```
const char* pos = std::find(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

you are working on `const char*` so you can't bind the result to `char*`, it must respect the `const` keyword.

therefore the correct way to achieve this is:

```
const char* pos = std::find(line, line + length, space);
  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Igor and Nawaz answered your question, I'll just add that if your compiler allows `C++11`, you'd take a good habit by using `std::begin` and `std::end` **for standard library containers and arrays** (and not a pointer like this as I originally wrote).

```
const char line[] = "whatever accessible char array";
const char * pos = std::find(std::begin(line), std::end(line), space);
```

Comment: Good idea in general, but not in this case: `std::begin` and `std::end` won't work with a raw pointer. If you had the actual array that the pointer points to this would be okay.